# Using parallel command to run multiple commands with switches

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

I have a situation where I need to run 2 commands at same time for a specific time.
So, I installed parallel, but I am unable to run the commands successfully .
My objective is running wpa_supplicant over terminal and dhclient , but to do them individually I have to quit one in order to execute the other on the same shell .

```
parallel -j0 --timeout 60  wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext ::: dhclient wlan0
```

I used the `-j0` switch to set the 2 commands for one processor only, and I set the timeout with the time frame I want those command to run .

I am using a raspberry PI on this project with minibian image.

Anyone here have an idea how to get this done?

Comment: Why not just do the first command in the background by appending an ampersand (`&`)?

Comment: "parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit." if i use (&&) between wpa_supplicant command and dhclient , but if i insert only 1 (&) then only wpa_supplicant runs but it does not run dhclient command .

Comment: No, I meant `timeout 60 wpa_supplicant ... &` followed by `timeout 60 dhclient ...` without any `parallel` at all.

Comment: Because in a shell only one command is executed at time , wpa_supplicant connects to wifi station and don't exit by itself after successful connection .

Comment: Can you explain better how it is supposed to work? When should the programs exit? Which one first?

Comment: Both programs must start simultaneous , and both should stop after a period time set in "timeout" configuration . If dhclient start first without wpa_supplicant establish the wifi connection then it exits without success and wpa_supplicant establish the connection right after that command closed with error , but no dhcp ip will be retrieved from Access Point .  All these command will run on a bash script that will start on boot .  This way it will not need user input and it will be automatically .